# How to post or share in Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to post a message or share a photo in my fb using FacebookSDK. I already follow the steps on how to install it. I'm done applying the login tutorial, but the problem now is how to post a message or share it into my FB using my app. There are a lot of tutorial like this [one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44640/integrating-facebook-and-parse-tutorial-part-1). I think this is already old for FacebookSDK. Sorry If I'm so noob for this. I know this not the right page to post this, but I don't have any idea now. If you have a tutorial on how to post or share. Please give me link. If ever, can you provide steps for this.

I already try [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), but It doesn't post or share.

**UPdate**

this is my code

```
import "ShareController.h"
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKMessengerShareKit/FBSDKMessengerShareKit.h>


@implementation ShareController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com"];

    FBSDKShareButton *button = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];
    button.shareContent = content;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {


    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];

    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    photo.image = image;
    photo.userGenerated = YES;
    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[photo];

    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    dialog.shareContent= content;
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;
    [dialog show];
}
```

here's the code for my login. I think this is simple code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291789/how-to-get-facebook-feeds-data/35292394#35292394

Comment: Please follow the above link you can share surely...

Comment: @JAGAT thanks man for this.

Comment: @JAGAT sorry I dont have an idea where I'm going to start

Comment: Share you code for login, also mention what problem you are facing, an error or something else.?

Comment: @TejasK I will update my post

Comment: That are the code that I have here. I think this is a simple code right?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: @user3818576 just put the code on your button click event. Nothing else.

Comment: @user3818576 Let me know if you have any query!!!

Comment: @JAGAT that's all i have here. sorry I'm still looking for tutorial here. that will connect to the answer that you give in your link

Comment: @JAGAT he is not using a custom button.

Comment: @TejasK I would like to ask about sharing photo. FBSDk gives sample file on how to share a photo, but my problem is. They are using contentUrl where you share photo outside of my phone, just like this one they are using url FBSDKShareLinkContent. How can I share photo in my album?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Do you want to open your photos, then select an image to share or you want to add an image to you project from your phone and then share it ?

Comment: @TejasK Yes that I what I'm trying to do, but I found out. It really doesn't work. Only FBSDKShareLinkContent will work.

Comment: @user3818576 you can share photos from your phone, check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: @TejasK I did that already. but nothing happened. I'm using new version of SDK and my version of xcode is 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You did not set permissions, to set the permissions:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[loginButton logInWithPublishPermissions: @[@"publish_actions"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
  NSLog(@"Process error");
} else if (result.isCancelled) {
  NSLog(@"Cancelled");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Logged in");
  }
}];
```

Also it is a good practice to check if user has granted the permission or not in your IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
{
    // code to share 
}
}
```

[image: These frameworks should be included]

Comment: I have problem in your code logInWithPublishPermissions: It gives me error.  this method doesn't exist. Is there something that I need to import?

Comment: #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

Comment: Did you go to build phases -> Link Binary With libraries, then click the + sign and add the frameworks.

Comment: @JAGAT the  logInWithPublishPermissions: method

Comment: @TejasK wait. what do you mean live? sorry for this.

Comment: @TejasK I add it already, I follow this steps https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started. I already add the App ID in my plist. maybe it take time for me to learn this. thanks anyway for your time

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696738/i-am-new-how-do-i-make-my-app-live-on-fb